# Array multidimencional en twig php - symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Trabajo con php - symfony y twig, tengo un array multidimencional `$datos = [$distributivos, $matriculados, $listaCalificaciones];`

Mediante un for en twig **como puedo llegar a distributivos?**, tengo el siguiente código

```
{% for type, items in datos  %}
        {{ type }}
        {% for key, value in items  %}
        {{ key }}
                                        
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Es un código de ejemplo que supuestamente recorre un array multidimencional en twig quiero navegar a distributivo que esta dentro del array datos

Comment: Mi bro, ¿podrías incluir la estructura de datos que tiene cada una de esas variables por favor?  Por otro lado, ese código de ejemplo, ¿qué genera?

Comment: Me refería a lo que hay dentro de la clase en texto/código, no al modelo ER en pantallazo. La segunda pregunta sigue pendiente :D